# Как разместить клавиатуру в два столбца (формируется автоматически)

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram-bot, клавиатура

**Как разместить клавиатуру в два столбца (или в три), если она формируется автоматически из базы даних?**

Есть функция и запрос

К примеру, у пользователя в базе 8 значений (текст) клавиатуры (у каждого пользователя могут бить розные значения). То есть по запросу он выводит (`teachers_keyboard.row(teachers)`) все в один столбец.

Функция:

```
elif message.text == KEYBOARD['TEACHER_SECH_TEACHER']:
    if not core.get_user_saved_teachers(message.chat.id):
        msg = 'текст1.'
        sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, msg)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, grupa_sech_teacher_week)
    else:
        teachers_keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
        for teachers in core.get_user_saved_teachers(message.chat.id):
            msg = "текст2"
        
            teachers_keyboard.row(teachers)

        teachers_keyboard.row(KEYBOARD['TEACHER_CANCEL'])
        sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, msg, reply_markup=teachers_keyboard)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, teacher_sech_teacher_week)
```

Запрос:

```
def get_user_saved_teachers(user_id):

    query = """SELECT teacher_name FROM saved_teachers WHERE telegram_id = ? ORDER BY added_time"""

    saved_teachers_raw = DBManager.execute_sql(query, (user_id,)) or []

    saved_teachers = []

    for teacher in saved_teachers_raw:
        saved_teachers.append(teacher[0])

    return saved_teachers
```

Answer (score 0):

подсчитав сколько элементов тебе вернёт бд можно рассчитать количество строк клавиатуры и добавлять их списком в teachers_keyboard

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: он возвращает 8 строк, то есть каждая кнопка отдельно, я мне нужно чтобы получилось 4 строки и в каждой строке по две кнопки

Comment: @Last_Arkhangel В классическом API бота кнопки можно группировать  в список списков - например, по 2 кнопки в каждом из вложенных списков (типа такой структуры `[ [1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8] ]`). Возможно в вашем случае также надо преобразовать линейный список `teachers` в двухуровневый, и его уже передать в `teachers_keyboard.row()`.

Comment: @GrAnd А как это сделать правильно в моем случае, преобразовать линейный список teachers в двухуровневый

Comment: @Last_Arkhangel Если элементов чётное количество, то можно такой конструкцией `teachers_grouped  = list(zip(teachers[::2], teachers[1::2]))`. Если нечётное, то последний элемент потеряется, так что просто добавьте его в конец.

Comment: @GrAnd Как правильно вставить `teachers_grouped`, выдает сообщение `'list' object has no attribute 'to_dict'`. Пробовал разные варианты.